# How to make this simple string function "pythonic"

Tags: python, string

Coming from the C/C++ world and being a Python newb, I wrote this simple string function that takes an input string (guaranteed to be ASCII) and returns the last four characters. If there’s less than four characters, I want to fill the leading positions with the letter ‘A'. (this was not an exercise, but a valuable part of another complex function)

There are dozens of methods of doing this, from brute force, to simple, to elegant.  My approach below, while functional, didn’t seem "Pythonic".

NOTE: I’m presently using Python 2.6 — and performance is NOT an issue.  The input strings are short (2-8 characters), and I call this function only a few thousand times.

```
def copyFourTrailingChars(src_str):

    four_char_array = bytearray("AAAA")
    xfrPos = 4

    for x in src_str[::-1]:
        xfrPos -= 1
        four_char_array[xfrPos] = x
        if xfrPos == 0:
            break

    return str(four_char_array)


input_str = "7654321"
print("The output of {0} is {1}".format(input_str, copyFourTrailingChars(input_str)))

input_str = "21"
print("The output of {0} is {1}".format(input_str, copyFourTrailingChars(input_str)))
```

The output is:

```
The output of 7654321 is 4321
The output of 21 is AA21
```

Suggestions from Pythoneers?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would use simple slicing and then [`str.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) to right justify the result using `A` as `fillchar` . Example -

```
def copy_four(s):
    return s[-4:].rjust(4,'A')
```

Demo -

```
>>> copy_four('21')
'AA21'
>>> copy_four('1233423')
'3423'
```

Comment: @VigneshKalai - Wow!  That is amazing!  Sure am glad I asked!

Comment: @SMGreenfield I did not answer that it was anand s kumar :)

Comment: @anand : you can also pass the string directly as a parameter, which makes it more intuitive.

Comment: @kmario23 I guessed you are talking about the *Demo* , yea you are correct there. Thank you, fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can simple adding four sentinel 'A' character before the original string, then take the ending four characters:

```
def copy_four(s):
    return ('AAAA'+s)[-4:]
```

That's simple enough!

Comment: I LOVE this -- so clever -- totally out-of-the-box thinking!

Answer (score 4):

How about something with string formatting?

```
def copy_four(s):
    return '{}{}{}{}'.format(*('A'*(4-len(s[-4:])) + s[-4:]))
```

Result:

```
>>> copy_four('abcde')
'bcde'
>>> copy_four('abc')
'Aabc'
```

Here's a nicer, more canonical option:

```
def copy_four(s):
    return '{:A>4}'.format(s[-4:])
```

Result:

```
>>> copy_four('abcde')
'bcde'
>>> copy_four('abc')
'Aabc'
```

Comment: your canonical version looks real cool -- but being a Python newb I'm having a hard time understanding the syntactical trick(s) you used, particularly {:A>4}.  Can you describe what you've done here?

Comment: @SMGreenfield - that right-aligns `>` the sliced string `s[-4:]` in a field `{}` with a maximum length of `4` characters, and fills in any strings that are too short with the character `A`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use slicing to get the last 4 characters, then string repetition (`*` operator) and concatenation (`+` operator) as below:

```
def trailing_four(s):
    s = s[-4:]
    s = 'A' * (4 - len(s)) + s
    return s
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
def copy_four_trailing_chars(input_string)
  list_a = ['A','A','A','A']
  str1 = input_string[:-4]
  if len(str1) < 4:
    str1 = "%s%s" % (''.join(list_a[:4-len(str1)]), str1)
  return str1
```